# Disable DomSanitizer completely in Ionic/Angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I'm trying to completely disable the $sce service of Angular in Ionic, however I have no idea where to place the code.

Here's the snippet I need to insert:

```
angular.module('myAppWithSceDisabledmyApp', []).config(function($sceProvider) {
// Completely disable SCE.  For demonstration purposes only!
// Do not use in new projects.
$sceProvider.enabled(false);  });
```

I'll be moving to a whitelist later - but I need to know where to put this code. I've put it in main.ts, page.ts, app.module.ts, and every time I get the following error:

```
Cannot find name 'angular'.
```

Can you point me in the direction of where I should be placing this code, or what I'm doing wrong?

Edit: here is the full code of app.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule, ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicModule, IonicErrorHandler, Platform, App } from 'ionic-angular';
import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { Page1 } from '../pages/page1/page1';
import { Page2 } from '../pages/page2/page2';
import { TutorialPage } from '../pages/tutorial/tutorial';
import { Users } from '../providers/users';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    Page1,
    Page2,
    TutorialPage
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    Page1,
    Page2,
    TutorialPage
  ],
  providers: [{provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}, [Users]]
})
export class AppModule {}

angular.module('MyApp', []).config(function($sceProvider) {
// Completely disable SCE.  For demonstration purposes only!
// Do not use in new projects.
$sceProvider.enabled(false);  
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help @georgeawg I've added the full code of app.module.ts to the post - it still throws the `Cannot find name 'angular'.` error. I'm assuming it's because I haven't declared Angular properly, but I'm not sure how to and all the other Angular features work. Cheers

Comment: You are trying to inject AngularJS code into an angular2/@angular framework. Angular2 handles security differently. See [@angular API Reference - DomSanitizer](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/platform-browser/index/DomSanitizer-class.html) and [@angular Developer Guide - Bypass Security APIs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/security.html#bypass-security-apis).

Comment: Experience shows that even extremely good programmers cannot be trusted with judging things like "you know all inputs are safe".  -- @mprobst [Martin Probst, Google, Angular Team](https://github.com/mprobst).

Comment: See also [@angular complete DOM security schema. Pull #8869](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/8869).

Comment: Hi George, Thanks for your assistance - knew there was a difference between the 2 but it didn't click until just then. Thanks for sending me down the right path. (Also, there's **no way** I'd use anything insecure in public code, this was just so I could get anything working so I could use whitelisting later, alas I was looking at AngularJS examples the whole time) Cheers